# How to Invoke Click to Open this Dropdown Menu

Tags: vb.net, button, drop-down-menu, webbrowser-control

I would like to press a button to make this dropdown menu that is in a webbrowser open.

**Here is the code html...**

```
<div class="nfTabSelectionWrapper" id="directDisplayStringId"><a class="nfTabSelection nfTabSelection--active mentPicker standardHeight" href="#"><div class="mopNameAndLogos"><span class="nfTabSelection--text card-type-text mentActive">Options</span><div class="logosContainer"><span class="logos logos-inline"></span></div></div><span class="ui-svg-icon ui-svg-icon--chevron pull-right pickerArrow"></span></a></div>
```

**Image of Dropdown Menu...**

[image]

**I tried with this code, but it did not work:**

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("directDisplayStringId").InvokeMember("click")
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event of the dropdown is most likely bound to the `<a>` element located within the div (seeing as it is only referring to `#`).

Try getting the first `<a>` element of the div and click that:

```
Dim directDisplayStringIdDiv As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("directDisplayStringId")

If directDisplayStringIdDiv Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("directDisplayStringId doesn't exist.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return
End If

Dim anchorElements As HtmlElementCollection = directDisplayStringIdDiv.GetElementsByTagName("a")

If anchorElements.Count <= 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("No anchor elements found.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return
End If

anchorElements(0).InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: @SérgioWilker : ...which is very ambiguous. What error do you get? I can't believe it doesn't work because it follows the HTML structure perfectly. See my update and tell me which message box is shown.

Comment: Here it says that directDisplayStringId doesn't exist!

Comment: @SérgioWilker : So it cannot find the element, which either means that it is located inside an `<iframe>` or that you are calling your code too early. -- Where/how are you trying to do this? In a button? Automatically? -- Could you please add some more code in the question _**(both HTML and VB.NET)**_ to help me see the bigger picture?

Comment: The button is not inside an Iframe and I am calling the code through a button that I tighten myself, after the website loads and the published code is all about the button going up the hierarchy. Unfortunately :/

Comment: @SérgioWilker : Hmm... Hard problem to diagnose... Also I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that the code _"is all about the button going up the hierarchy"_?